# hyperlink data is not exporting in radgrid excel export

Tags: asp.net, excel

i have two hyperlink columns in radgrid, when i try to export it to excel, the column is blank in excel sheet,if i use excelML my date column showing time which i could not able ti change it,please help me out, thanks in advance.

RadGrid11.MasterTableView.AllowFilteringByColumn = false;
                RadGrid11.MasterTableView.AllowPaging = false;

```
            RadGrid11.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData = true;
            RadGrid11.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            RadGrid11.HeaderStyle.BorderWidth = 5;
            RadGrid11.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            RadGrid11.ExportSettings.FileName = "Batch";
            RadGrid11.MasterTableView.GetColumn("SelectColumnID").Visible = false;
            //RadGrid11.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = GridExcelExportFormat.ExcelML;
            RadGrid11.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
```

aspx page:

'>

```
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="MemberName" HeaderText="Member Name" SortExpression="MemberName" UniqueName="MemberName" >
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="RadG" Width="130px" VerticalAlign="Top"/>
    <ItemStyle Font-Names="Times New Roman" HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Size="10px" Font-Bold="false" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="hpLinkName" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" Font-Underline="true" 
            Text='<%#Eval("MemberName")%>'>
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix for this. You have to set the text first on the hyperlink then you can set the value on the export in the RadGrid1_ItemCommand function. See example below.

```
private void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items)
    {
          // get the unique name of the column to grab the control
          var hyperlink = item.FindControl("UniqueColumnName") as HyperLink;
          if (hyperlink == null)
          {
               continue;
          }

          // set the value of the cell being exported 
          // to the value of the hyperlink text
          item["TemplateColumn"].Text = hyperlink.Text;
    }
}
```